# What is the best way to instantiate a class and let it do the work

Tags: java, database, class, servlets, constructor

I am using a servlet that is taking parameters from a registration form, what I am doing at present is using a java class that will process on those parameters and store them in Database but I feel like the way I am using this class is wrong. My code is like this:

```
UserRegister ureg=new UserRegister(name,age,sex,country);
```

And that is all, my constructor in the class will do the entire job from processing the data to storing it in db by calling methods in the UserRegister class on its own.

Is it the right approach, or there is any better way of doing this?

EDIT:  my UserRegister class will do just some processing on the data and it will call a business layer to store the data, it itself is not going to interact with the database.
What I am asking is what approach is to be followed when you have a class where after initializing there are just a fixed series of steps to be performed inside it

Comment: This is probably better asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com ; here on Stack Overflow it is IMHO considered "not constructive".

Comment: @Brian: thanks for telling about programmer.stackexchange.com, I was unaware about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my constructor in the class will do the entire job from processing the data to storing it in db

Wrong. Never program this way.

Come out of c'tor ASAP after intializing the basic necessity of it's class.

The method in which `UserRegister` object is created. use that method to call methods on `ureg` object.

For example:

```
public void processRequest(name, age, sex, country)
{
    UserRegister ureg=new UserRegister(name,age,sex,country);
    ureg.updateSomeFields();
    ureg.doSomeBusinessLogic();
    ureg.prepareDBData();
    ureg.storeInDb();
}
```

This is only an example to improve your current design. however you should have some utility classes also. class `UserRegister` should have data and behaviour which represent a User, only a User.

Design Utility classes such that they take input in a format, do some calculation and then return the output data to it's caller. So, whenevr `processRequest` method needs a job to be done, it doesn't do it by itself but calls another method (it may be in same class or some other class)

EDIT:

> What I am asking is what approach is to be followed when you have a class where after initializing there are just a fixed series of steps to be performed inside it

It depends on the nature of those steps. Find out how are they related. are they related to User? if yes, put them as methods in User class. if not, combine related steps together, create a class with meaning full name and use it. When creating a separate class, try to design in such a way they can be used as utility and not only for the current purpose.

Comment: You mean, I should call methods inside UserRegister class from my servlet's method after creating the UserRegister object. Ok it is fine but what if I need to call methods inside UserRegister class always in a fixed order, then isn't it better to let the UserRegister class to call those methods on its own?

Comment: Programmatically it's possible but think about design also. is it a task to be done by `UserRegister` class. does the method name in `UserRegister` class conveys that what all steps it is going to perform.?

Comment: Imagine them to be just like the methods you wrote above, then what should be done?

Comment: You should have different classes for BusinessLogic, DBLogic. one word solution is: `MVC`.

Comment: @Azaodious What I am doing at present is, my servlet will create a `UserRegister` object and this class will be responsible for some basic processing, thereafter this class will call a static class say `UserAccountsDB` that takes parameter to be stored in DB.

Comment: Is this alright? And there is one more problem what if some problem happens while storing in DB or while processing, how do I let my servlet know about it so it can display appropriate error to user

Comment: yes, very much. but read about models and javabeans when learning MVC. For propagating error back to user, you can fill `ResponseObject` with appropriate data.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [Multi-tier architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture).

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at one of the many MVC frameworks available to handle extracting the parameters into a form and then using a business layer to do your processing and a persistence layer for your database access.

Check out [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/) for an example of the many many MVC frameworks around and how they integrate with other Java frameworks. Even if you don't end up using it, there are some great videos on how effectively these combinations of frameworks can be used to allow you to evaluate various technologies to create a 3 tiered environment.

Answer (score 0):

Normally its better to break the functionality up into pieces. This give you the ability to unit test each part individually. Create a user object from the input from the form. Then make a call to a data access layer to save the user.

Read up on MVC. I personally like Spring MVC. You can get the info from the form in an object. Then you use a service layer to do any transformation needed. From there you can persist the user.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are mainly for initialization tasks, where the objects gets created. I would move all the logic of storing in the DB to some methods. Also if the process on storing data in the DB takes a lot of time, then hanging to this user's "thread" is not a good idea at all, you could do the work in an async way, async being supported from Servlet 3

As other have said here, Spring MVC would be a very good place to look at.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this approach.  What exactly will `UserRegister[] ur = new UserRegister[10]` do?  What if I have `UserRegister ur = readfromDatabase(...)`. Since this function has to create a `UserRegister` to return, the data gets saved again to the database!?  Weird and confusing.  What if I want to save to a file and not a database?

Better to separate the data object creation from data persistence.

Comment: what exactly is meant by data persistence? And please elaborate your answer a little more

Comment: Data persistence = the storage of data outside of memory.